# Deleting object from a view in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-urls

I have a page that shows a list of objects and I want to add a button beside each one to enable the user to delete it. I've found a few questions about similar scenarios online but for some reason I keep getting errors when I try to replicate the solutions.

Here is the delete function in views.py:

```
def delete_dish(request, pk):
    query = Dish.objects.get_object_or_404(pk)
    supermenu = query['supermenu'].pk
    query.delete()
    return redirect('foodmenu:menu', supermenu)
```

Here is the form in the HTML template:

```
            {% if not supermenu.dish_set.count == 0 %}
            <ul>
            {% for dish in supermenu.dish_set.all %}


                <li>
                {{ dish.name }} - {{ dish.description }}
                <form action="{%  url 'foodmenu:delete_dish' dish.id %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit">X</button>
                </form>

                </li>


                    {% if not dish.price_set.count == 0 %}
                    <ul>
                    {% for price in dish.price_set.all %}
                        {% if price.label %}
                            <li>{{ price.label }}: {{ price.cost }}</li>
                        {% else %}
                            <li>{{ price.cost }}</li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                    </ul>
                    {% endif %}


                {% endfor %}
            </ul>

            {% else %}
            <p>No dishes on this menu!</p>

        {% endif %}
```

And here is the urls.py:

```
app_name = 'foodmenu'
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('dish/delete/<int:dish.id>', views.delete_dish, name="delete_dish")
]
```

When I click the button, the browser goes to ./dish/delete/1 (1 being the pk of the object), but Django returns a 404 error.

Comment: Are you sure there is an object with `pk=1`? Note that usually a database does *not* take the smallest unassigned integer, it keeps iterating.

Comment: just `query = get_object_or_404(pk);  query.delete()`. Because `query` is your model.

Comment: I'm not sure. 1 is just the number that gets returned from `dish.id` where it is called in the HTML template. I'm very new at this so I'm a bit lost still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `query = Dish.objects.get_object_or_404(pk)` you should use [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404) shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST

@require_POST
def delete_dish(request, pk):
    if request.method
    query = get_object_or_404(Dish, pk=pk)
    supermenu = query.supermenu.pk
    query.delete()
    return redirect('foodmenu:menu', supermenu)
```

Also change your url pattern to this:

```
path('dish/delete/<int:pk>/', views.delete_dish, name="delete_dish")
```

**UPD**

As  @daniherrera mentioned in his comment, you probably want to check request's method, to prevent accidental deletions. For this you can use `require_POST` decorator.

Comment: fix your answer. remove `supermenu = query['supermenu'].pk` also `return redirect('foodmenu:menu', query.pk)` is ok.

Comment: after `query.delete()`, query does not exist. this will raise error here `return redirect('foodmenu:menu', query.pk)`

Comment: @daniherrera I've tested it, `query.pk` after deletion return None. Probably this is because of old version of Django, currently I'm able to use only 1.10, but I rollback my answer.

Comment: This `supermenu = query['supermenu'].pk` looks weird, I can't understand how you can pass value to an model instance that way.

Comment: @Lemayzeur you are right. I missed this part. Probably OP means something like this: `query.supermenu.pk`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, my bad. When you delete a model the pk becomes null. Nice.

Comment: I tried this but it somehow is preventing the template from rendering. Now if I try to load a page that includes delete buttons, I get a "NoReverseMatch" error: `Reverse for 'delete_dish' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['dish\\/delete\\/\\<int\\:dish\\.pk\\>$']`

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, to avoid anti patterns, may be it is a good idea to check action is a POST: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46614

Comment: @neverwalkaloner, may be a good opportunity to use [require_POST()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST)

Comment: @daniherrera good catch! Added this to the answer, thank you!